How to paste with indentation in emacs (evil) on pressing only p?
It seems a profane requirement though after years I'm still unable to paste text with the correct indentation.
Has anybody a solution that doesn't require anymore steps than hitting p in visual mode after yanking some code from firefox?
def f():
    foo=""
    -> How to paste here with hitting only `p`

e.g.
yanked from scratch buffer:
a=""
b=""

Pasting with cursor below char f of the word foo results in
def f():
    foo=""
    a=""
b=""

My latest attempt is toggling aggressive-indent-mode back and forth which indents just everything beneath the cursor"

Since the pasted text might have any old indentation, you will need to reindent somehow. If you can find a function that reindents however you want, then you can advise the pasting function to run the reindenting function after the paste.

I'd be already happy if even two lines from the scratch buffer would would be pasted with correct indendation. Nevermind the browser

With toady's modifications, we have two cases to discuss.

Depending what you select for yanking, we can succeed to yank only with p,
see picture below, the relative line #2 was typed by me and with only p the
yanked text is correct.



Yanking from scratch buffer: what you get is correct, legally in Python: you
selected two lines, not a column with two elements and for first line you forced
the position to be indented. The second line start at column 0 and this is correct
case, b in this case is a global variable; you can get out of function implementation
with a character placed at column 0.

More about the previous paragraph: do the following - yank only an a and then type a
couple of ENTERs, you wil get the point always indented. At this moment you can
play with TAB key, one press will dedent the point position and inserting a character
in column 0 is a mean to leave the function implementation. These are Python rules.
You can get yourself the conclusion for this question.

Thank you. The problem remains regardless of the location e.g. pasting into a function docstring doesn't work neither

For docstrings (and not only for that) it is useful to use a code formatter, e.g. black, together with the emacs package apheleia - just save the file after pasting an all will be OK. Note that other editors behave same way.
